# stripe payment for flutter web

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments

I am trying to make a web app in flutter(later android/ios also) and want to do payment using stripe with multiple options like card, apply pay etc. how should I approach this?

The official flutter_stripe package in pub.dev says the web is experimental so I have no idea what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use Stripe Checkout [0] (hosted by Stripe, you generate a link and redirect your customer to payment page), or use Payment Element [1] with the official Stripe.js package.

[0] https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=checkout

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=elements

Comment: So there is no pure flutter way to do that. Only separate checkout and js (the second link)?

Comment: I see there's an early stage [flutter_stripe_web](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_stripe_web) from the same developer, but it's not official. I wouldn't recommend using that for production. So for now it's best to stick with the above flows.