# How to integrate stripe payment for flutter web using stripe.js

Tags: flutter, flutter-stripe

In my flutter web application, I want to integrate stripe payment gateway(cards,google pay and apple pay) using stripe javascript function. am not able to find any documentation regarding the same

Someone help me to integrate stripe for flutter web

Comment: you can't using js. why don't you use https://docs.page/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe ?

Comment: yes i have used this for flutter mobile app and for web app flutter_stripe_web used  this plugin. but in that they have mentioned like "This package is in a very early stage so be cautious to use it in production." so as per suggestion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77444687/stripe-payment-for-flutter-web#:~:text=You%20can%20either%20use%20Stripe,js%20package.&text=So%20there%20is%20no%20pure%20flutter%20way%20to%20do%20that